# How to resolve cannot find symbol in Java?

Tags: java, linux

I'm Working on Java, Following is my code snippet,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();
envMap.put("Dumyy", "myValue");
Process p = envMap.start();
```

With above i got following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol Process p = envMap.start();
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: @ALL, I understood the error, the reason for error is that i should call start method on instance of ProcessBuilder.

Comment: how come Map<String, String> has start() method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`envMap` is a map and it does not have a method `start`.
Your code should be:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();
envMap.put("Dumyy", "myValue");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: exactly! How did I miss that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you do not have that class on your classpath.

Another reason can be that you did not build your project and you are working with an older .class file which does not have what you need.

Just a note: the class `Map` does not have a `start()` method so it will not work even if you fix the symbol issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class. But... what's

> envMap.start()

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the sample given in the ProcessBuilder doc- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html
In the example you havent passed any command for the process builder to start.